# Microsoft Deployment Toolkit 2013 over Workgroup

Tags: windows, operating-system, mdt

I have been trying to deploy Win 8 using the new MDT 2013 over a workgroup as we are not using a domain.

Here are the required info:

```
 Workgoup: Bigben1  
 username: user145  
 password: pa$$  
 PC name: NDA145  
 DeployRoot=\\NDA145\DeploymentShare$
```

Now when I try to load the ISO in a VM workstation and try to deploy, I get the USER CREDENTIAL screen where I am asked for Username, Password and DOMAIN. All three are mandatory fields.

I have tried NDA145, \NDA145, Bigben1 and many other things but it always gives me **Invalid Credentials: The network path was not found

[image]

Here is the question -  WHAT DO I ENTER IN THE DOMAIN FIELD? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the VMware network of your guest is connected as a bridge.
You need to type the computer name where your MDT share is if you are in a workgroup.